# Setting timeout for BasicDataSource

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

We have a Hibernate based application (to MySQL server) deployed in Tomcat 7.0.x

We needed to implement a timeout property where if the query runs longer than this set threshold value, the connection-query-thread should disconnect and return back to pool.

Do we have any property that can set either in Tomcat / Hibernate config?

Can removeAbandonedTimeout be used for this purpose?
[https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html]

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${database.pwd}"></property>
    <property name="initialSize" value="8"></property>
    <property name="maxActive" value="30"></property>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"></property>
</bean>


    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"></property>   ??
```

Answer (score 0):

***defaultQueryTimeout*** from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html

is the one which controls query/execution timeouts

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers, as links can get obsolete. Try to update your answer with the essential part of what you found useful in the link you provided.
While this link may solve the question, 
[including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-??based-answers) 
of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking.